# Antlr4 C++ target

Tags: c++, antlr, antlr4

We're starting a project where we will need to parse python source files in a C++ application. I've used Antlr2 a while back to generate a few compilers, but this is the first time I'm using Antlr4.

It looks like the c++ antlr4 target is fairly active at https://github.com/antlr/antlr4-cpp

So, my question is basically what is the status of the Antlr4 C++ target, is it ready to start being used? To use the C++ target, what just grab the Antlr4 source, and copy the Antlr4-cpp into this tree and build?

Note, I don't need something that's absolutely stable and guaranteed never to change, just something thats basically stable enough to start being used, if there are small/moderate API changes in the future, thats perfectly fine, I understand that it looks fairly early.

If the antlr4-c++ target is NOT really ready, what parser generator would you recommend for generating a C++ target python parser?

thanks

Comment: SO is not the right place to ask status questions. Subscribe to the dev mailing list to read what's going on. You can even read the list via http without being subscribed.

Answer (score 6):

The ANTLR4 C++ target is now ready for use: https://soft-gems.net/the-antlr4-c-target-is-here/. Only needs some minor organizational stuff and must be merged to main repo.

Comment: do you know the status of your PR to be merged in the main branch ? I have to support python / js / c++ bndings for a simple language ... will definitly use yours for now. Thank you very much

Comment: Ter told me he plans to do the merge in October, so it's maybe 6-8 weeks to go.

Comment: its fine. I think you maintain the base remote in your repository ? tks for your work.

Answer (score 3):

This repository has the latest source code for the ANTLR 4 C++ target.

https://github.com/antlr/antlr4-cpp

Here is a good discussion about the status of the target.

https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/antlr-discussion/HV2QpwwjtLg