# Finding macro variables in c files using java

Tags: java, c, regex, macros

I am trying parse a c file and find all the variables that begin with "Apple_". I read the entire c file to a string and then use a regex to get all the variables. But I have a macro defined as:

`#define IAMMACRO(var,ext) var##ext`

so if I have

```
IAMAMACRO(Apple_,Variable)
```

I need to get the value Apple_Variable after the parsing and not Apple_.

PS: I prefer an easy solution.

Comment: The easiest solution is to preprocess the file with a C compiler before processing. The next easiest is to write a standards-compliant C preprocessor.

Comment: Is there any way to preprocess the c File in Java itself :| there is no gcc compiler in the systems here. or I could've used gcc -e.

Comment: Use gcc's -E flag: `gcc -E -o test.p test.c`

Comment: You could try a Java based C preprocesor like [jcpp](http://www.anarres.org/projects/jcpp/).

Comment: @Ram I am trying to create a software that is using this function. What if the user who is using the software does not have the gcc compiler?

Comment: Perhaps you can find a suitable tool [in this SO question thread](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1645538/is-there-a-standalone-c-source-preprocessor).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As as understand, you want :

- to read, then parse C (C++?) file ;
- to embed it in a software;
- to have an *easy* solution :)

So, solutions to use gcc galaxy is rather complicated, and heavy (in fact, you dont care about compiling).

Advice : dont try to parse yourself. It is a big job !

Solution: **just** parse. Use a library to do that.

**Use ANTLR4 (not so easy), with an already-made grammar for C/C++:**

ANTLR4:  http://www.antlr.org/

Grammar for C++: https://github.com/antlr/antlr4-cpp

see also that:
[Antlr4 C++ target](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30179887/antlr4-c-target)

hope it helps !